# Restart Silverlight application when it crashes?

Tags: c#, silverlight-3.0

I have a silverlight 3 application. When an unexpected exception occurs the error childWindow pops up. I Want to know what code should i write behind the "OK" button so that the application restarts over when the user clicks it.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A quick and simple fix would be to just reload the page that the application is hosted on; you can use the [`HtmlWindow.Navigate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.browser.htmlwindow.navigate%28VS.95%29.aspx) method to accomplish this. If you don't want to reload the whole page, you could stick the application in an `<iframe>` and just reload that.